# Aggregate on Datetime Column for Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a table which stores Login information for  employees

Sample Data for the login Table is

```
 EmpID  Status     [Time]
 100    SignIn    2013-03-07 11:41:44.473
 101    SignIn    2013-03-07 10:41:44.473
 100    SignOut   2013-03-07 12:41:44.473
 101    SignOut   2013-03-07 11:41:44.473
 101    SignIn    2013-03-08 11:41:44.473
```

I want the result to be

```
EmpID   SignIn                    SignOut
 100    2013-03-07 11:41:44.473    2013-03-07 12:41:44.473
 101    2013-03-07 10:41:44.473    2013-03-07 11:41:44.473
 101    2013-03-08 11:41:44.473    NULL
```

I tried to use PIVOT

```
Select EmpID,[SignIn],[SignOut]
from 
(Select EmpId,status,LoginTime from Login)p
 pivot
(
 min(Logintime)
 For status in ([SignIn],[SignOut])
)pvt
```

But the above query leaves out the last row for the `Employee` `101` having `SignIn` Time but `no SignOut` value

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4e44/1) for generating table data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get it like this:

```
SELECT  l1.EmpID
        , l1.LoginTime [SignIn]
        , l2.LoginTime [SignOut]
FROM    Login l1
LEFT JOIN   
        Login l2 ON 
        l2.EmpID = l1.EmpID
AND     CAST(l2.LoginTime AS DATE) = CAST(l1.LoginTime AS DATE)
AND     l2.status = 'SignOut'
WHERE   l1.status = 'SignIn'
```

Note that in case if you had more than one signin/signout per day for an employee and you wanted to get his first `SignIn` and last `SignOut` for a day, you would have to change the query:

```
SELECT  l1.EmpID
        , MIN(l1.LoginTime) [SignIn]
        , MAX(l2.LoginTime) [SignOut]
FROM    Login l1
LEFT JOIN   
        Login l2 ON 
        l2.EmpID = l1.EmpID
AND     CAST(l2.LoginTime AS DATE) = CAST(l1.LoginTime AS DATE)
AND     l2.status = 'SignOut'
WHERE   l1.status = 'SignIn'
GROUP BY
        l1.EmpID, CAST(l1.LoginTime AS DATE)
```

And here is another query that also works for multiple signin/signouts of a user during the same day. This will list all of his signin/signouts in a day:

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT  *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY EmpID, CAST(LoginTime AS DATE) ORDER BY LoginTime) 
                AS num
    FROM    Login
)

SELECT  l1.EmpID
        , l1.LoginTime [SignIn]
        , l2.LoginTime [SignOut]
FROM    cte1 l1
LEFT JOIN   
        cte1 l2 ON 
        l2.EmpID = l1.EmpID
AND     CAST(l2.LoginTime AS DATE) = CAST(l1.LoginTime AS DATE)
AND     l2.num = l1.num + 1
WHERE   l1.status = 'SignIn'
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a1e7/1/1)** for last two queries that handle multiple signin/signout scenarios of a user in a single day, for that purpose I added user with `EmpID` 102 to sample data.

Comment: Thanks for providing different solutions !

Comment: You're welcome, I thought it might be good to cover some additional situations so I added second and third query.

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track using the `PIVOT` function, you just needed a way to assign a `row_number()` to each row based on the `empid`, `status` and `date`/ You can use the following `pivot` code:

```
Select EmpID,[SignIn],[SignOut]
from 
(
  Select EmpId, status, 
    LoginTime, 
    cast(logintime as date) date,
    row_number() over(partition by empid, status, cast(logintime as date)
                      order by logintime) rn
  from Login
)p
pivot
(
  min(Logintime)
  For status in ([SignIn],[SignOut])
)pvt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f402f/6).

You will notice two new columns in the subquery.  One to generate a `row_number()` for each row and the second to generate the `date` without the time.  Both of these columns are used in the `GROUP BY` but not displayed in the final select. They are used so you will can get multiple rows for each employee on everyday (if needed).

The result using @IvanG's data from the sql fiddle is:

```
| EMPID |              SIGNIN |             SIGNOUT |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   100 | 2013-03-07 11:41:44 | 2013-03-07 12:41:44 |
|   101 | 2013-03-07 10:41:44 | 2013-03-07 11:41:44 |
|   101 | 2013-03-08 11:41:44 |              (null) |
|   102 | 2013-04-08 12:41:44 | 2013-04-08 13:41:44 |
|   102 | 2013-04-08 16:41:44 | 2013-04-08 17:41:44 |
|   102 | 2013-04-08 19:41:44 |              (null) |
```

Comment: @praveen I cannot help it, I love these questions! :)

Comment: When I saw this question was about pivot and wasn't solved, I thought "bluefeet probably isn't online" :)

Comment: @IvanG It is kind of sad that people just expect my answers! `:D`

Comment: @bluefeet I guess they can't help it because you're so good at it :D