# Aggregate on Datetime Column for Pivot into 4 columns

Tags: sql, pivot, datefield

I need help with pivoting a column from one into 4, to look like this:

[image: example]

Going on from this post [Aggregate on Datetime Column for Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264563/aggregate-on-datetime-column-for-pivot/77288498#77288498)

I got the first part done with pivoting from one column into 2 columns: Sign in and Sign out. But I need to have 4 columns with sign in and sign out for the same day but different times, since employee punches in and out for lunch but it's the same day. I'm looking for one row per employee ID and day with 4 different time stamps of that same day.

[image: example]

Comment: How should you handle cases where an employee has more or less than 4 punches for a day? What if they never punch out for lunch?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the value in column status at the beginning. Then apply to this output the steps you followed for the 2-columns solution.

```
select
EmpId
, SignIn1
, SignOut1
, SignIn2
, SignOut2
from (
  select EmpId,  [Time], Status = Status +          convert(varchar(10),row_number() over (partition by EmpId, Status order by [time])) from login) q
    pivot (min([Time]) for Status in ([SignIn1],[SignOut1],[SignIn2],[SignOut2])) p
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean edit the value in status column plus my data in the table is 24hrs format not AM and PM.